# What does onset of oxidation mean in Cyclic volammetry

Tags: electrochemistry, redox, cyclic-voltammetry

I've read a few posts on here on how to calculate onset of oxidations in Cyclic voltammetry. However, I dont know what it actually means when comparing the onsets of oxidations of two different molecules, for example, two conjugated semiconducting polymers.

Comment: I am not an expert on this subject, but my guess is that the onset potential means the voltage at which the activation barrier for the electrochemical reaction is overcome.

Comment: Not really about the onset itself but with conjugated polymers you can have peaks broader than expected due to a distribution of effective conjugation length whatever reason.

Answer (score 2):

The concept is explained very nicely here [Cyclic voltammetry](https://www.ossila.com/pages/cyclic-voltammetry). I would say the term onset of oxidation is slightly vague but one should talk about $E_{onset}$ as shown in the figure. Qualitatively, the current (on the y-axis) begins to rise very fast, that corresponding potential $E_{onset}$ tells us that after this potential, the kinetics of oxidation will become appreciably fast.

[image]